# Should I send release message to a casted object?

Tags: objective-c

If I'm converting a CF type to Foundation type, should I send release message the the foundation type?

```
NSString *name = (NSString*) rawName;
CFRelease(rawName);
//should I [name release]; ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't send another release messages. These are different *references* to the *same* object.

Usually when mixing Core Foundation methods and Cocoa methods, you keep the object in whatever your base is (so if you're working in Cocoa, keep it as an NSString) and just cast it when you need to use one of the other framework's methods (such as passing the string to a Core Foundation method, simply cast it to CFString then instead of keeping multiple references around).

Comment: So since these are different references to the same object, does this mean that releasing one of the references is sufficient after I have done?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means. And if you want to keep a reference around longer, you would have to take ownership of that reference with a retain or copy message, then release it later. In your example, once you call CFRelease() on rawName, you can't safely access rawName or name anymore.

Comment: In my case, I'm adding firstName to NSMutableArray and then I'm CFRelease rawName, am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. But you can also just cast the "rawName" on the fly, so you could do something like: [myMutableArray addObject:(NSString*)rawName]; with no issues

Answer (score 1):

In this situation *name and *rawName point to the same object. CFRelease()'ing rawName will cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when you try to use name.